# Property accessible in initialize not accessible in template?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When instantiating a new view, I'm passing in a model. I have access to that model in the "initialize" property, but I can't reference it when I'm trying pass the model into a template. Any idea why?

```
var postView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize : function() {

           // returns model 
            console.log('the model we are interested in',this.model); 
            this.render();
        },

        el : "#blog-post",

        template : function() {

            // returns undefined
            var model = this.model;

            return _.template($('#postview').html(), {
                post : model
            });
        },

        render : function() {
            var self = this;
            this.$el.html(self.template);
        }

    });
```

I'm instantiating it using a method in another view:

```
readMore : function(e, index) {
            var self = this;
            var newView = new postView({
                model : self.collection.models[index].toJSON()
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a function to `this.$el.html`:

```
this.$el.html(self.template);
```

That's the same as saying:

```
var f = this.template;
this.$el.html(f);
```

So what does `html` do when you pass it a function? Well, from the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function):

> **.html( function )**
>
> A function returning the HTML content to set. Receives the index
>   position of the element in the set and the old HTML value as
>   arguments. jQuery empties the element before calling the function; use
>   the oldhtml argument to reference the previous content. Within the
>   function, `this` refers to the current element in the set.

When you pass `html` a function, it will call that function but `this` won't be what you think it is, `this` inside the function will be the DOM element that is having its HTML set.

I think you want to call `this.template` yourself and hand its return value to `html`:

```
this.$el.html(this.template());
// ------------------------^^
```

That way `template` will have the view as its `this` as you expect it to.

Comment: I ended up implementing things a little differently, but fundamentally this is the right answer. Instead of returning _.template(...., I set that to a variable and returned variable. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Best guess would be this no longer refers to the context of the view. if you log this within the function what does it show.

EDIT-
Actually not sure if this will give the expected results, i normally use handlebars but i think the setup for _.template and hanblebars is pretty similar. Your template template normally wants a plain java object passed to it other wise you would have to access the variables you want in yours like post.attributes.name, however if you just pass the toJSON version of your model you can access the attributes without the need for post.attributes.

Also you can compile your template once then just refer to it, no need place it as a function and have it grab from the DOM every time (assuming it never changes). Below is an example of what i mean. In your template you would then have <%= name %> etc to grab you model attributes.
    var postView = Backbone.View.extend({

```
        initialize : function() {

           // returns model 
            console.log('the model we are interested in',this.model); 
            this.render();
        },

        el : "#blog-post",

        template :  _.template($('#postview').html()),


        render : function() {

            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;

        }

    });
```

Oh also the convention normally is that render returns 'this' so if you want to call it from some where else and attach it to a new part of the page you can do it calling     `postView.render().el`

Answer (score -1):

You may be passing the model, but you're not receiving it in your view. Try:

```
initialize: function(model) { ...
```

Comment: Um, Backbone views set `this.model` automatically when you `new View({ model: ... })`.

Comment: @muistooshort is right. That's how I instantiated the view. Passing in the model. Like I say, I can see the model when I log it from within 'initialize'