# Backbone handlebars variables return 0 (zero)

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm having some trouble rendering a handlebars template with some data. The variable placeholders are replaced with "0", instead of the variables value. I've logged the JS object going into the the compiled handlebars template, it all seems fine. The template itself renders fine, it's just the variables that don't work.

```
tpl: function(){
  var template_id = "#tpl-" + this.partial,
  partials_elem = $('<div>' + partials + '</div>');
  return Handlebars.compile($(template_id, partials_elem).html());
},
```

and

```
this.$el.html(this.tpl(this.data)).appendTo(this.holder);
```

where

```
this.data = {first_name: "test"}
```

(I've hardcoded that in there as well, console.log one line before this.tpl(this.data) gives me this value as well)

the handlebars template looks like this:

```
<div id="tpl-test">
  {{first_name}}
</div>
```

I'm using RequireJS, Backbone and Handlebars.

I hope someone can help me out!

Thanks,
Rik

EDIT:
Solved by changing

```
this.$el.html(this.tpl(this.data)).appendTo(this.holder);
```

to:

```
var tpl = (this.tpl())(this.data || {});
this.$el.html(tpl).appendTo(this.holder);
```

Comment: This is the same underlying problem as [**Property accessible in initialize not accessible in template?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24192234/479863) but not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is that you call function tpl to render with your object, you should call the return of  the function, not the function itself, i made a jsfiddle for this, saving the result of tpl function in a variable then use it like

```
this.$el.html(this.compiledTemplate(this.data));
```

please check this jsfiddle
     http://jsfiddle.net/mfarouk/ttnL8oo5/1/

Comment: I'm sure I was using the return of the function, otherwise templates with no variables wouldn't render either, which they did, I've worked around the problem by using hbs.

Comment: @rikudesu: You can call jQuery's [`html` with a function argument](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) and jQuery will execute the function (but not with the arguments that a compiled Handlebars template is expecting). So `x.html(compiled_handlebars_template)` works but doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @muistooshort, thanks solved it by using the following code:

`var tpl = (this.tpl())(this.data || {});`


`this.$el.html(tpl).appendTo(this.holder);`

Comment: it is the same as my answer